# How to trigger sysdiagnose if my Volume Down button is broken?

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware, apple-diagnostics

I need to trigger sysdiagnose on my old iPhone 5S. However it looks like its physical VolumeDown button does not work, neither for volume nor for any combinations.

How can I trigger sysdiagnose without pressing Volume Down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access this functionality through AssistiveTouch on your iPhone, which creates an on screen icon that replaces all the hardware functions of your device for device accessibility, however this is particularly useful when physical buttons on your device are broken.

This can be enabled by opening `Settings > General > Accessibility > AssistiveTouch`, and turning on AssistiveTouch.

Then for your specific issue you can enable the Analytics option as a single or double tap option, a long press or 3D touch of the button that is brought up.

[image: Screenshot of setting up Assistive Touch]